# Green function for Laplace's equation in complex three dimensional space

Tags: singularities, complex-numbers, differential-equations, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

The Green function for Laplace's equation in three dimensions for a source at the origin is
$$ \nabla^2 G(\mathbf{r})= \delta(\mathbf{r}) =\delta(x)\delta(y)\delta(z) $$
where  is $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{z}$ is the position vector.
The solution is
$$ G(\mathbf{r})=\frac{-1}{4\pi r}$$
where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. The Laplacian of this is zero everywhere except $r=0$.

But what if $x,y,z$ are allowed to be complex? Consider the point $x=0$, $y=a$ and $z=ia$ for some $a$.
At this point we have $r=0$, but also $\delta(\mathbf{r})=0$.
Is the Laplacian of $G$ equal to zero at this point even though $G$ itself is undefined?

Comment: How do *you* define $\nabla$ (or $\nabla^2$) in a complex space in your question ?  This seems (to me) to be effectively a six dimensional space.

Comment: Im not sure, is $ \nabla= \mathbf{x} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_r}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})+ \mathbf{y} (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_r}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i})+ \mathbf{z} (\frac{\partial}{\partial z_r}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}) $ where $x=x_r+ix_i$ etc. sensible? Then $ \nabla^2=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_r}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})^2+ (\frac{\partial}{\partial y_r}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i})^2+ (\frac{\partial}{\partial z_r}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i})^2$, but this gives $\nabla^2 G=0$

Comment: * but this gives $\nabla^2 G$ undefined for $r=0$*

Comment: I'm suggesting moving it to [math.se] as it seems a better fit to them - there is no physics here (that I can see).

Comment: Well the method of images uses sources placed in complex dimensions, which are integrals over the Green function. See for example "Image Solution for Poisson’s Equation in Wedge Geometry" (Nikoskinen and Lindell). But if you think the question  will have more success in Mathematics or MathOverflow I'd be happy to move it.

Comment: **At this point we have r=0** But isn't $z^2=(ia)^2=-a^2$?

Comment: yes, but $y^2=a^2$, which cancels the $z^2$ part.